# How to enable a particular hidden folder in Mac 10.7.3?

Tags: macos

I am working as a iPhone developer,

To enable hidden files/folders in finder windows:

1. Open Finder
2. Open the Utilities folder
3. Open a terminal window
4. Copy and paste the following line in:

   `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`
5. Press return
6. Now hold ‘alt’ on the keyboard and right click on the Finder icon
7. Click on Relaunch

Using this steps to follow, finally all hidden files are show in all menus, but i want active/enabled a particular folder in Mac. In windows Just right click the hidden file --> Go to folder option then active the particular folder, similarly How to do this in Mac?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: As stated by trojanfoe, there is a way to hide individual files and folders using chflags.  Please reconsider marking another answer as the correct answer.

Comment: You may be able to get more answers on http://apple.stackexchange.com - but having said that, I would recommend @trojanfoe's answer below.

Comment: Moved this over to SuperUser:  http://superuser.com/questions/1156597/how-do-i-show-a-particular-hidden-folder-in-finder-on-os-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type these commands on terminal:
**For Showing hidden folder:**-

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

**For Hiding folder:**-

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
killall Finder
```

Comment: I tried this, all the hidden files shown it, then How to make enable a particular hidden folder

Comment: see this [link](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/06/hide-folders-mac/).

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `chflags` command line tool ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chflags.1.html))?

```
$ cd ~
$ chflags nohidden Library
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to enable this feature on a per-folder basis in Mac OS X.